# How to remove quotes and backslashes from an object when stringifying it (without regex)

Tags: json, node.js, regex, neo4j

I am using Neo4j which has a clause to allow setting multiple properties at once:

```
 MATCH (p:Person)
 WHERE p.email = '${userEmail}'
 SET p += ${argsToUpdate}
 RETURN p AS Person
```

However, I cannot get `argsToUpdate` into the query because Neo4j is looking for a string exactly as it appears here:

```
 { email: 'test@test.com', age: 1337, colour: 'blue' }
```

I could use `JSON.stringify(argsToUpdate)` regex and strip \ and " but that is subpar because some properties could contain those characters. Maybe they could be encoded first.

I also tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(argsToUpdate))`.

I used `util.inspect(argsToUpdate)` and it works perfectly, but my dev lead won't accept it because it's a node.js debugging method.

Is there a simple way to achieve this another way?

I don't want to do something like a for loop like this:

```
 let args = '{ '
 for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(argsToUpdate).length; i++) {
     args += `${prop[i]}: ${key[i]}`
 }
 args += ' }'
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? The issue is that `argsToUpdate` contains a variable number of properties. I want it to be dynamic so that the code isn't so brittle. Is there anything available in ES6+ including babel that can achieve the result of `util.inspect(argsToUpdate)`?

Comment: what neo4j driver are you using? you should be able to pass the parameter as a javascript object and let the driver worry about this kind of thing!

Comment: what exact error are you getting? cypher won't like the param name `${argsToUpdate}`, the syntax is either `{param}`, `$param` or `$\`{param with braces and spaces in the name}\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default neo4j driver, you should be able to pass all parameters to the query in standard javascript data structures and not worry about string escaping like this. I think the issue is that your parameters are named incorrectly.

Cypher parameters must be composed of unicode letters and cannot start with a currency symbol. Names enclosed in backticks can contain spaces. So, should take forms like the below.

- `{someParam}`
- `$someParam`

Or even something like the two below.

```
{ `some param with spaces in the name` }
$`some param with spaces in the name`
```

With that in mind, the query below should work.

```
session
  .run('MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.email = $userEmail SET p += $argsToUpdate RETURN p AS Person', {userEmail: 'test@test.com', argsToUpdate: { email: 'test@test.com', age: 1337, colour: 'blue' }})
```

Comment: Thanks Dom. Your samples are plenty sufficient to solve the issue. I will edit your post to append the functioning solution.

Comment: I see now how to properly read the Neo4j docs also. It is worth mentioning for others that on pages such as http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/, the 'Parameters' text blocks are referring to the structure of the object parameter passed into the query. I was previously confused by those.